# Rails 3.1 - Extra result of each loop?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

This is really simple, but i'm going slightly mad and probably missing something that's staring me in the face. Can anyone help?

Basically, I have a simple each loop that's returning an extra rogue line. Even when there's nothing in the db, I get one line returned!

My show view including the loop is:

```
  <p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<p>
  <b>Header:</b>
  <%= @mailer.header %>
</p>

<p>
  <b>Subtext:</b>
  <%= @mailer.subtext %>
</p>

<div id="" class="" padding-left: 30px;>    
<h3>Mailer Products </h3>

<ol id="mailer-Product-list">
<% @mailer.mailer_products.sort_by { |mailer_products| mailer_products.position }.each  do |mailer_product| %>
    <%= content_tag_for :li, mailer_product do %>
    <%= mailer_product.product.cat_no %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
</ol>   

    <%#= link_to 'Done', @product, :class => "standard-button" %>
</div>



<%= form_for([@mailer,@mailer.mailer_products.build]) do |f| %>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :product_id %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :product_id %>
    </div>

    <div class="field">
    <%= f.hidden_field :mailer_id, :value => @mailer.id %>
    </div>

    <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Add Product" %>
    </div>
<% end %>


<%= link_to 'Edit', edit_mailer_path(@mailer) %> |
<%= link_to 'Back', mailers_path %>
```

The controller code is:

```
class MailersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @mailer = Mailer.find(params[:id])
     respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @mailer }
     end
   end

class MailerProductsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @mailer_products = MailerProduct.find(:all)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render :json => @mailer_products }
    end
  end
end

end
```

Comment: What do you get when you type `mailer.mailer_products` on console (with the appropriated mailer)?

Comment: Is it a `has_many :mailer_products` in your `Mailer` model? If so, try echoing a `@mailer.mailer_products.count`.

Comment: Pastin the working rather than the not working version of the code is rather bizarre.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your call to `form_for` looks like this

```
form_for([@mailer,@mailer.mailer_products.build]) do |f|
```

You get an extra blank item because that's what calling `.build` on `mailer_products` does: it appends a new instance to the array

When the form is after the loop this doesn't matter, but when things are the other way around the loop will be on the modified array

Answer (score 0):

My usual mistake is adding a `<%=` instead of a `<%` on the loop...

```
<%= @foo.each do |itme| %>
# do stuff
<% end %>
```

which should be

```
<% @foo.each do |itme| %>
# do stuff
<% end %>
```

Double check your tags...

Comment: Thanks, tags are exactly as above so that's not it sadly.